# How to block a file from being created?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, virus

So, something that may or may not be a virus (apparently >95% of virus detection programs don't recognize it, yet it's clearly not doing anything good) is doing something with a file located in some faraway place under my user's AppData folder, in some folder that claims to be both hidden and a protected OS file. For some reason, my virus protection (Avast) is scanning the file over and over and over again multiple times a second. Upon Googling the file's name, I found that it's also a web page. Google has no cache of it, because of it's robots.txt file, but the page appears to be blank. Both the site and the name of the file is "ls.hit.gemius.pl"
The first time I deleted it from "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\*forgot the rest of the path*\" I also denied everything all permissions to that folder from the properties. All was quiet until I started up my computer again today, at which point it was back. In a different folder though. "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*some combination of letters and numbers*\" So I cleaned that out as well, but I couldn't restrict access to this one. It doesn't even give me the option to view the properties of the folder. File isn't back right now, but it probably will be if I reboot again.

I usually want to do something like this to save space on my computer because there are plenty of other folders that have stuff created in them and not deleted ever. (These countless so called "temp" folder where apparently every program that does anything creates stuff with a ton of seemingly random numbers and letters in a seemingly random temp folder are absolute BS. Nothing in them is temporary.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: Not at all. I don't really have any highly valuable information on this PC. While it would be nice to investigate what is creating this file, my main goal is to just reduce my hardware usage. I am generally not willing to go to the lengths of reinstalling everything.

Comment: `ls.hit.gemius.pl` is listed in [Czech and Slovak filters for AdBlock and Adblock Plus](https://adblock-czechoslovaklist.googlecode.com/svn/filters.txt) so it is presumably ad related